# Select from a view using where clause on indexed column in Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle

We have a Oracle database table called `StockDailyQuote` which contains billions of rows. There are two indexes: on `TradeDate` (a `Date` field) and on `StockTicker` (a `string` field). This table is actually a partitioned table and on each `TradeDate` there is an individual table. So we never query against it using

```
SELECT * FROM StockDailyQuote
```

because it is impractical to get any result. Instead we always use a `WHERE` clause on `TradeDate` and the the speed is acceptable.

Now we have compiled a `view` out of `StockDailyQuote` table (joined some other tables to get useful information). Because we can't specify the `TradeDate` at this stage so our view looks like this (this is a simplified version):

```
create or replace view MyStockQuoteView as
SELECT t1.StockTicker, t2.CompanyName, t1.TradeDate, t1.ClosePrice
FROM StockDailyQuote t1 join CompanyInstruction t2 on t1.StockTicker = 
t2.StockTicker
```

And I always try to query against this view with a `WHERE` clause on `TradeDate` column. I thought when oracle sees my query `SELECT * FROM MyStockQuoteView where TradeDate = '20170726'`, it would be smart enough to add the indexed where clause to the sql and then send it to the engine so the query should be as equally fast as `SELECT * from StockDailyQuote where TradeDate = '20170726'`, assuming my other joins do not take much time. But it doesn't behave like that: it takes really long time to return values. I can only assume it queries against the whole  view and then uses the where on the returned value. This makes this query impractical to use. So how can I solve my problem? One solution is to make a procedure and run it daily and save one day's data to a table. But is there some other options?

Comment: However, [it looks like indexes should come into play when using a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923802/how-do-table-indexes-come-into-play-when-using-a-view)... Consider collecting the explain plans for your queries and compare.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to see the query plan `SELECT * FROM MyStockQuoteView where TradeDate = '20170726'`.
Oracle normally understands what it needs to read to the partition inside the view. 
You can try to explicitly specify the hint, for example:

```
SELECT /* + full(MyStockQuoteView.StockDailyQuote) */ * FROM MyStockQuoteView where TradeDate = '20170726'
```