# SQL Server view performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a view with three different tables. each table contains some duplicate values. To remove duplicates I have used `UNION`, but it causes performance issues.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[UserView]
AS
    SELECT * FROM A
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM B
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM C
END
```

If I use `Select * from A` the performance will be faster. But when using the above query creates performance issues. I want to remove duplicates from three tables and increase performance in view

Sample

Table A:

```
insert into a (empid, empname, managerid) values (1, 'test1', 2)
```

Table B

```
insert into b (empid, empname, managerid) values (1, 'test1', 2)
insert into b (empid, empname, managerid) values (2, 'test2', 3)
```

Table C

```
insert into c (empid, empname, managerid) values (1, 'test1', 1)
```

Expected

```
(1, 'test1', 1)
(2, 'test2', 3)
(1, 'test1', 2)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated with expected output

Comment: I'd generally suggest seeking a solution upstream. Why do you have multiple tables containing the same "type" of things (such that it makes sense to merge them)? Why are you producing duplicates at all? As a *general* problem, if you have multiple tables with the same type of data, and you need to eliminate duplicates and combine them, why do you think an *external* technique will work better than the built in `UNION` function?

Comment: Plus do not select *, especially for unions and views, if you change any of the table structures without them all matching it will break your view.

Comment: You could try using some sort of `where not exists` logic, but it probably won't perform any better. But as others have said, fixing the source of the dupes is your best bet.

Comment: My first question would be, do you need `SELECT *`. The next would be do your different tables *really* contain rows that are identical in ***every*** column? Your sample data suggests not, why why use `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`?

Comment: See also this question about [How do table indexes come into play when using a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923802/how-do-table-indexes-come-into-play-when-using-a-view).    Indexes can help increase performance....  (unless you do `select * from` without a where-clause...)

Comment: Since your question is based on performance, please [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) so that your execution plan can be reviewed

Comment: provide your execuation plan by pasting it [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question

Comment: Or to put it another way, you're looking for a generic solution to combining multiple data sets and eliminating duplicates. *if* such a solution exists and *if* it performs better than `UNION`, *why* would the implementers have not switched to using it?

Comment: I have used UNION ALL  and created clustered and non clustered in for all three tables but still facing the same performance.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit painful, but if you have indexes on `(empid, empname, managerid)` in the tables and no duplicates within a table, then you can use:

```
select empid, empname, managerid
from a
union all
select empid, empname, managerid
from b
where not exists (select 1
                  from a
                  where b.empid = a.empid and
                        b.empname = a.empname and
                        b.managerid = a.managerid
                 ) 
union all
select empid, empname, managerid
from c
where not exists (select 1
                  from a
                  where c.empid = a.empid and
                        c.empname = a.empname and
                        c.managerid = a.managerid
                 ) and      
      not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where c.empid = b.empid and
                        c.empname = b.empname and
                        c.managerid = b.managerid
                 ) ;
```

Basically, this eliminates the duplicates between the tables, so you can use `union all` instead of `union`.  The index is important for performance.

Comment: In my case the same table can have multiple duplicates. I have created an index on three tables. But still facing the same issue